# Vaadin - ListSelect component unselect on click

Tags: java, components, vaadin, selectlist

I try add item click listener to ListSelect component, I want to unselect item on click, when click item is selected. 
In standard way I dont see any possibility to do this ;/ maybe some one know the way ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the default ListSelect there is probably no other way. If you're willing to use other components however, there is. The [FilterTable add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory/-/directory/addon/filteringtable) has the unselect behavior built-in. It can be styled to look just like a ListSelect (or prettier, for that matter).